# Redis (or other means) to share memory between machines

Tags: java, redis, spring-boot

I need to share a large (~70MB) memory object between two different machines (java spring-boot rest service behind a load balancer).

As a first shot I tried to fiddle with Redis [configured master/slave](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-redis-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04), configured with `slave-read-only no` 
  but still I cannot understand how to configure it in order to write data from the slave:

```
master$ redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379                 
127.0.0.1:6379> set mytest "written by **master**"

slave$ redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379
127.0.0.1:6379> get mytest
"written by **master**"
```

so far not bad but when I write from the slave

```
slave$ redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379                 
127.0.0.1:6379> set mytest "written by **slave**"
master$ redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379                 
127.0.0.1:6379> get mytest
"written by **master**"
```

Have I misunderstood something?

Is there a better/simplier way to do it?

Is redis the right solution for this issue?

Comment: slave is read-only, you can read/write to master and only read from slave. Yes Redis will fit well in your scenario, but even better check the data tpes it exposes http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro - maybe you can break that 70MB objects in many smaller ones

Comment: I've edited the question: "slave-read-only no" in both master and slave redis.conf

Comment: Data written to a slave will not be replicated and it can easily be erased on a resync with the master. Also because the default is read-only slave someone can also believe it is a bug actually and not your actual intention.

Comment: In this case redis does not fit my scenario (?!). Data can be recalculated by any server indipendently I only need to have them syncronized.

Comment: Apparently, redis is not the best solution in your situation. The only solution I see in this moment is to set up 2 redis instances on every machine (one master and one slave). Using the master on machine A, you can transfer information to the slave (that replicates that master) placed on machine B and vice versa. What do you think about that?

Comment: Seems correct but ... I think I will end up having doubled the memory footage on each machine.